# Cucumber+Capybara. PhantomJS Crashes or not rendering page?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

Hello Stackoverflow community, I use Cucumber+Capybara with Chrome/firefox drivers for testing Backend/FrontEnd with Canvas/React.js elements and I now I stuck with PhantomJS (Poltergeist).

All my tests work fine and very stable with Chromedriver/Firefox, but I have a lot of unexpected issues/errors with headless browsers

Usually, I get two type of errors:
1. Backend, JS, login page, capybara raised error when I visit the page:

```
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
  Background: Log In backend                                # features/HS_smoke_backend.feature:5
    Given HS Backend Login Page                             # features/step_definitions/links.rb:5
      PhantomJS client died while processing {"id":"34954a92-1af2-4e1f-a37c-0342d8d04179","name":"visit","args":["https://backend.xxx.com/",1000]} (Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient)
      ./lib/capybara/session.rb:252:in `visit'
      ./lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      ./features/step_definitions/links.rb:6:in `/^HS Backend Login Page$/'
      features/HS_smoke_backend.feature:6:in `Given HS Backend Login Page'
```

2. If I run the same test on CI (Codeship) with latest PhantomJS, then I get another error(but it works fine locally with ChromeDriver).I guess something wrong with security module, that's why PhantomJS crashes.
   **Any thoughts?**

**Error(Codeship)**

```
    Background: Log In backend                                # features/HS_smoke_backend.feature:5
    Given HS Backend Login Page                             # features/step_definitions/links.rb:5
    And I Log In with login "admin" and password "admin123" # features/step_definitions/actions.rb:3
          Unable to find field "user" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
          ./lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
          ./lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
          ./lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
          ./lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:92:in `fill_in'
          ./lib/capybara/session.rb:780:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
          ./lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          ./features/step_definitions/actions.rb:4:in `/^I Log In with login "([^"]*)" and password "([^"]*)"$/'
          features/HS_smoke_backend.feature:7:in `And I Log In with login "admin" and password "admin123"'
```

**Login page:**

```
    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
        <div id="root"><div data-reactroot="" class="login-body"><div id="login"><form name="form-login"><div class="image"><img src="/static/bd592ccc4d8f1bd5ec54f462b6da0e82.png" width="192px" height="" alt="logo"></div><div class="block1"><div class="name"><p>Username</p></div><input type="text" id="user" required="" placeholder="" value="admin"></div><div class="block2"><div class="passw"><p>Password</p></div><input type="password" id="pass" required="" placeholder="" value="admin123"></div><div style="padding: 15px; height: 50px;"><p class="forgot"><a href=""></a></p></div></form><div id="submit"><input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Log In"></div></div></div></div>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script><iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="FirebugUI" style="border: 0px; visibility: visible; z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 300px; display: none;"></iframe>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**backend.feature:**

```
Feature: Regression backend
  As a account manager
  I would like to see working backend

  Background: Log In backend
    Given HS Backend Login Page
    And I Log In with login "admin" and password "admin123"

  @javascript
  Scenario: Smoke test backend
    And I click on Profile
```

**links.rb**

```
Given(/^HS Backend Login Page$/) do
  visit "https://backend.xxx.com/"
end
```

**actions.rb**

```
When(/^I Log In with login "([^"]*)" and password "([^"]*)"$/) do |login,password|
  fill_in('user', :with => login)
  fill_in('pass', :with => password)
  click_button('Log In')
end

And(/I click on Profile$/) do
  page.find(:css,'#dropdownMenuArrow').click
  page.find(:css, '#profile').click
end
```

**env.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/spec/test_app'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'yaml'

Capybara.app = TestApp


Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false


Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
        options = {
            :timeout => 1000,
            :extensions => [],
            :js_errors => false,
            :debug => false,
            :window_size => [1600, 1200],
            :inspector => true,
            :phantomjs_options => ['--load-images=no',
                                   '--debug=no',
                                   '--proxy-type=none',
                                   '--disk-cache=false',
                                   '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
                                   '--ssl-protocol=tlsv1',
                                   '--web-security=false'],
                  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist


Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome
end

Before '@selenium' do
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1600, 1200)
end
#World(Capybara::DSL)
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bundler', '~> 1.1'
gemspec

gem 'xpath', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/xpath.git'

group :doc do
  gem 'redcarpet', :platforms => :mri
end

group :test do
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

**My gems:**

```
actionpack (4.2.7.1)
actionview (4.2.7.1)
activesupport (4.2.7.1)
addressable (2.5.0)
afm (0.2.2)
archive-zip (0.7.0)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.14.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capybara (2.12.0)
capybara-screenshot (1.0.14)
childprocess (0.6.1)
chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
cliver (0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.1)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-rails (1.4.5)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.17)
fuubar (2.2.0)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gherkin (4.0.0)
hashery (2.1.2)
i18n (0.8.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
io-like (0.3.0)
json (1.8.6, default: 1.8.3)
launchy (2.4.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.1, 5.8.5)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
pdf-reader (1.4.1)
phantomjs (2.1.1.0)
poltergeist (1.13.0)
power_assert (0.2.6)
pry (0.10.4)
psych (default: 2.1.0)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.5)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (4.2.7.1)
rake (12.0.0, 10.5.0, 10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
redcarpet (3.4.0)
rspec (3.5.0)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium-webdriver (3.1.0)
sinatra (1.4.8)
slop (3.6.0)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.6)
ttfunk (1.4.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
websocket (1.2.4)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
yard (0.9.8)
```

Comment: Theres not a lot you can do about PhantomJS crashes other than making sure you're running the latest PhantomJS (2.1.1 as of now, there is also a 2.5 beta available) and making sure that any JS is transpiled to a maximum of ES5.  Any ES6 features in use (let/const/=> functions, etc) can cause the JS to be ignored or cause PhatnomJS to crash.  You might also want to enable `js_errors` while debugging. Beyond that, why are you specifying `Capybara.app = TestApp` ? Are you sure the URL you're attempting to contact is reachable from CodeShip?

Comment: Additionally, after `click_button('Log In')` you should have an expectation for something that appears on the page after a successful login to ensure the login completes before you perform any other actions on the page, otherwise the login can be aborted, not actually return the session cookies, etc.

Comment: Hello @ThomasWalpole, thank you for an answer! You're right, Capybara.app = TestApp is not required, I guess I took it from the previous project. Also, I added expectation after steps to verify successful login. With js_errors => true I see: "ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property '_temp'". From Local machine PhantomJS keeps crashing. URL is reachable.

Comment: First step would be fix that JS error by finding out where _temp is being defined, and fix the error.  Other than that look through the JS the app is requesting and make sure it is actually ES5 compliant (no let/const/etc)

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWalpole, the problem was with the login page, with js errors, and I decided to switch to real browser bc Codeship supports it